# How to modify an USB stick in order to have a device node as /dev/sda1 instead of /dev/sda?

Tags: linux, usb, udev, partition-table

I have a udev rule for USB sticks with fat32 format. The rule contains such attributes:

`SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd?1", ...`

Normally, it works very well for USB sticks that I tested so far, since the most USB sticks are represented in the device node as `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sdb1`.

Now, I have a special USB which has a device node as `/dev/sda`. The `blkid` command of this USB stick returns such outputs:

`/dev/sda: UUID="AC9E-6C58" TYPE="vfat"`

Compared to the normal one (`/dev/sda1`), I miss the `PARTUUID` attribute.

Furthermore, The command `sfdisk -l /dev/sda` returns these outputs:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1021 cylinders, 247 heads, 62 sectors/track
Units: cylinders of 7840768 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0
   Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda2          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda3          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
```

This USB has 0 in the `/dev/sda1` row. However, the normal USB stick has such entries:

```
   Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1          0+   2703-   2704-   7835620    b  W95 FAT32
            start: (c,h,s) expected (0,1,11) found (0,0,57)
            end: (c,h,s) expected (1023,125,46) found (975,125,46)
/dev/sda2          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda3          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
```

Based on this [discussion](https://serverfault.com/a/338952/373877), it means that the USB stick doesn't have a partition table.

If I don't want to change my udev rules, how can I modify this USB stick? A normal re-partition either with Windows tool or Gparted doesn't change this layout.

If changing the partition layout is not possible, how can I change my udev rule so that it can deal with USB stick which either recognize on /dev/sda or /dev/sda1?

Thanks.

Update: I changed the term "mount" with "device node" to avoid confusion. Thanks to Austin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that you have no data you need to keep on the USB stick, and that it shows up as `/dev/sda`, run the following as root:

```
wipefs -a /dev/sda
```

That will erase the FAT32 signature (and any other filesystem signatures too) from the device so it shows up as empty, at which point Both GParted and the Windows disk manager should create a partition table when you go to reformat it.

Also, just to clarify terminology, the kernel does not 'mount' devices to `/dev`, it creates device nodes there which can be used to interact with the devices (though, if you've got udev, it may be creating the device nodes instead of the kernel), but mounting is an operation that specifically refers to filesystems (more specifically, to 'mount X to Y' implies that X contains a filesystem, and you're making that filesystem accessible directly at location Y, which is not what's happening when device nodes get created).

Comment: Thanks Austin. In Gparted: Device -> create partition table, which partition table shall I choose? msdos, gpt or other? what is the portable one for all OS?

Comment: @why2 msdos (possibly listed just as 'dos') is the only one that's truly portable.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution under Windows is by using `diskpart`:

1. Unplug the USB stick
2. Run the windows terminal or type `cmd` in the Windows start search field.
3. Type `diskpart` and type `list disk` in the new DiskPart window to see the current devices
4. Plug the USB stick, and execute again `list disk` to observe the correct disk number of the USB stick
5. Type `select disk=<number>`. Replace the `<number>` by the disk number of the USB stick that you want to reset.
6. Run `clean`, then `convert mbr`to create a new partition table on the USB stick.
7. Execute `create partition primary` command to create a new primary partition.